# FFMPEG - MAC OS Cannot Capture from Black Magic UltraStudio (Thunderbolt)

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, blackmagic

I have Black magic UltraStudio Express that captures SDI or HDMI and Connected to MacBook via Thunderbolt when I list devices I get the Audio but not the video :

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""

ffmpeg version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --disable-jack --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.0/include/openjpeg-2.3 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa261600d80] AVFoundation video devices:

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa261600d80] [0] FaceTime HD Camera

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa261600d80] [1] Capture screen 0

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa261600d80] [2] Capture screen 1

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa261600d80] AVFoundation audio devices:

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa261600d80] [0] Blackmagic Audio

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa261600d80] [1] Built-in Microphone

: Input/output error
```

Any Idea why my FFMPEG does not see the device, Btw, other application sees the video just fine.

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to try the decklink device - ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#decklink

Comment: Thanks Mulvya, I am trying that at the moment but still having an issue to include the SDK packages into FFMPEG, do you have the instruction for that ? is there an FFMPEG version built --with-decklink ?

Answer (score 0):

Manaf-2:~ manaf$ ffmpeg -f -format_code Hi50 -f decklink -i 'UltraStudio Express' -c:a copy -c:v copy output.avi

ffmpeg version 2.8.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[decklink @ 0x7f893a801200] Cannot enable video input

Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Upgrade. Use this script to build a new binary: https://github.com/jb-alvarado/compile-ffmpeg-osx-linux

Comment: I tried the script, it seems its old and am getting lots of errors specially with the OS, the library was build for Mac OS10.10 and I have 10.13. Would you be able to help me with building my own FFMPEG with decklink ? Thanks for your support :)